# Python: Pandas compare two dataframes and get the different rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

compare two dataframes and get the different rows

have two df's

```
name    password   login_id
tom      1234         1
matt     4567         2
george   7469         
stuart                3
```

```
name    password   login_id
tom      1234         1
matt     7859         2
george   7469         5
stuart   4682         3
```

Need to get the changed value complete rows

```
expected output 

name    password   login_id
matt     7859         2
george   7469         5
stuart   4682         3
```

Need to get only rows which has changed in second df

Comment: i need to know which values are updated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) after setting `name` as the index in both the dataframes and use [`df.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) over axis 1.

```
mask = df.set_index('name').ne(df1.set_index('name')).any(1).tolist()
df1[mask]
     name  password  login_id
1    matt      7859         2
2  george      7469         5
3  stuart      4682         3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try merge with `indicator`

```
df2.merge(df1,how='left',indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
     name  password  login_id     _merge
1    matt      7859         2  left_only
2  george      7469         5  left_only
3  stuart      4682         3  left_only
```

Comment: `df2.merge(df,how='left',indicator=True).query('_merge=="left_only"')` we can use `df.query` too. Cool logic tho. +1